# isuue creating java class while running hadoop wordcount proram in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

**hii 
I am following this tutorial to run wordcount

```
http://edataanalyst.com/2013/08/the-definitive-cloudera-hadoop-wordcount-tutorial/#comment-257

cloudera@localhost ~]$ ls
datasets Downloads Music students.text WordCount_Classes workspace
Desktop eclipse Pictures Templates WordCount.java
Documents lib Public Videos WordCount.java~


[cloudera@localhost ~]$ javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/* -d WordCount_Classes/WordCount.java
```

no matter what i do i get this error
javac: directory not found: WordCount_Classes/WordCount.java
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options

i did create a dir by typing mkdir WordCount_classes

i have tried to check class path it returned blank

so i set it with this command

export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/*

even when  type echo

```
 $HADOOP_HOME OR PREFIX OR MAPRED ALL RETURN BLANK
```

replaced "usr" with cloudera, clouderauser, home but none worked.

please help thanks
sorry if i am not clear id did the best i can do im very new to programming world
thanks.**

Comment: Is WordCount.java present in the directory WordCount_classes?

Comment: yeah i pasted it into wordcount_classes still its giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong arguments with -d.

```
javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/* -d /home/cloudera/WordCount_Classes WordCount.java
```

Enter directory path as per your system

Comment: With -d you have to pass a directory as a parameter, where you have passed dir+filename as parameter. Correct way is `-d dir filename`. Check the space between dir and filename